# PyQT - Group cells in QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm searching how to create headers like HTML-tables in QTableWidget, something like that:[image]

I can do it in QTextEdit (HTML-table with images in cells), but I need custom cells like that:

[image]

so QTextEdit is not suitable for this. Is it possible at all and if is, how can I create it? Maybe not a QTableWidget, I just need editable table with custom cells and custom header.

All I see is just insert one big header image and set all columns according to that image, but how to create one row with one cell in it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> QTableView.setSpan(row, column, rowSpan, columnSpan)
>
> Parameters:
>    row – PySide.QtCore.int
>    column – PySide.QtCore.int
>    rowSpan – PySide.QtCore.int
>    columnSpan – PySide.QtCore.int
>
> Sets the span of the table element at (row , column ) to the number of rows and columns specified by (rowSpanCount , columnSpanCount ).

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QTableWidget, QHBoxLayout, QApplication, QTableWidgetItem )
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QBrush, QColor #,  QFont 

class Table(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("QTableWidget - Example of a cell merge")
        self.resize(660,300 );
        conLayout = QHBoxLayout()

        tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        tableWidget.setRowCount(7)
        tableWidget.setColumnCount(6)
        conLayout.addWidget(tableWidget)

        # Hide headers
        tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
        tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)

        #tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Column1','Column1','Column1'])  

        # Sets the span of the table element at (row , column ) to the number of rows 
        # and columns specified by (rowSpanCount , columnSpanCount ).
        tableWidget.setSpan(0, 0, 1, 6) 
        newItem = QTableWidgetItem("tableWidget.setSpan(0, 0, 1, 6)")  
        tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, newItem) 

        tableWidget.setSpan(3, 0, 3, 1)   
        newItem = QTableWidgetItem("tableWidget.setSpan(3, 0, 3, 1)")  
        tableWidget.setItem(3, 0, newItem)  

        newItem = QTableWidgetItem("Hello")  
        newItem.setForeground(QBrush(QColor(0, 255, 0)))
        tableWidget.setItem(3, 1, newItem)  

        newItem = QTableWidgetItem("pythoff") 
        newItem.setForeground(QBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0)))        
        tableWidget.setItem(3, 2, newItem)   

        self.setLayout(conLayout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    example = Table()  
    example.show()   
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]